# copy tab contents across different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I get an extraction from SAP that usually has 40 tabs. I then need to copy their contents in other tabs across another workbook - my template. This template is made of 40 input tabs. For each input tab there is always an extracted tab which contents I will paste. I have been trying to automate this task with the following code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub copytabs()
    Workbooks("test").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:PPP999").Copy
    Workbooks("test2").Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("test").Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1:PPP999").Copy
    Workbooks("test2").Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Workbooks("test").Worksheets("sheet5").Range("A1:PPP999").Copy
    Workbooks("test2").Worksheets("sheet5").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

This code does the work though very slowly. I tried to work on Array bu not luck.
Does any of you has a suggestion?
Cheers
Fabi

Comment: Hi there, the below it's not working. Have I missed something?   Workbooks("test").Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:PPP999").Copy
    Workbooks("test2").Worksheets("sheet1").Range ("B2")
    Workbooks("test").Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1:PPP999").Copy
    Workbooks("test2").Worksheets("sheet3").Range ("B2")
    Workbooks("test").Worksheets("sheet5").Range("A1:PPP999").Copy
    Workbooks("test2").Worksheets("sheet5").Range ("B2")

Comment: I need to paste over because my template has a lot of output tabs that feed from the input tab. Cheers. Fabi

Comment: See the answer that i posted. You may have to refresh the page

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `.Activate` and `.Select`. They make your code slower. You may also want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Also you can write the above code in a loop if the sheet names are like `Sheet1, Sheet2...Sheet40`

```
Option Explicit

Sub copytabs()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    Set wbI = Workbooks("test")
    Set wbO = Workbooks("test2")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To 40 Step 2
        wbI.Sheets("sheet" & i).Range("A1:PPP999").Copy _
        wbO.Sheets("sheet" & i).Range("B2")

        DoEvents
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

BTW creating a copy of workbook `test` and renaming it to `Test2` would be much faster?

**EDIT**

> my extraction has 40 tabs and each of them has a name. For example Praline 1617, Total Company 1617 and so on...Then I paste their contents in **tabs named exactly like their original**. So my template has the same tabs name of the extraction. – Fabi 1 min ago

Is this what you want?

```
Option Explicit

Sub copytabs()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wbI = Workbooks("test")
    Set wbO = Workbooks("test2")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In wbI.Worksheets
        ws.Range("A1:PPP999").Copy wbO.Sheets(ws.Name).Range("B2")

        DoEvents
    Next ws

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't rename the workbook because test2 has input and output tabs. This code works though I wouldn't know how to apply it considering that each tab has a specific name. Is there a way around?

Comment: What do you mean specific names?

Comment: my extraction has 40 tabs and each of them has a name. For example Praline 1617, Total Company 1617 and so on...Then I paste their contents in tabs named exactly like their original. So my template has the same tabs name of the extraction.

Comment: I have updated the post, you may have to refresh it to see it

Comment: I slightly adjusted your code. The macro unfortunately doesn't work. See below for details.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `For` loop indices to match your needs:

```
Sub copytabs()
    For i = 1 To 11 Step 2
        Workbooks("test").Worksheets("sheet" & i).Range("A1:PPP999").Copy Workbooks("test2").Worksheets("sheet" & i).Range("B2")
    Next i
End Sub
```

This avoids using `Select`.

Comment: Yup loop is the way to go

Comment: How should I define i though?

Comment: @Fabi  replace the **11** with your last sheet number.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in case the worksheets have specific names and to improve the readability of the code, then use the following code

```
Sub CopyPaste()

WSName = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet5")

For n = LBound(WSName) To UBound(WSName)
    With Workbooks("test").Worksheets(WSName(n)).Range("A1:PPP999")
        .Copy Workbooks("test2").Worksheets(WSName(n)).Range("B2")
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: There are 40 sheets :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout The OP can use `WSName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose("Column of worksheet's names")` or using collection of workheets (For Each statement)

Comment: I get the following error message Compile Error: Expected Erray. I must have missed something.

Comment: True but wouldn't that be an overkill :) The idea is to make things simpler. Wouldn't you agree? :)